# Enforce type is subtype of interface and extends number

Tags: typescript

I am working with these interfaces

```
/**
 * Interface for entities
 */
export interface Entity extends Object {
    readonly id: EntityId;
}

/**
 * Interface for collection-based state
 */
export interface Collection<T extends Entity> extends Object {
    readonly entities: { [key: string]: T };
    readonly ids: EntityId[];
}
```

And I am writing a helper function that given a path, increments corresponding value of an entity in a collection.

Example:

```
Collection.increment(myCollection, 'some-id', ['stats', 'total']);
```

And these are my current typings

```
    export function increment<
        C extends Collection<any>,
        E = C extends Collection<infer U> ? U : never,
        K1 extends keyof E = keyof E,
        V1 extends E[K1]= E[K1]
        >(collection: C, entityId: string, path: K1 | [K1]): C
    export function increment<
        C extends Collection<any>,
        E = C extends Collection<infer U> ? U : never,
        K1 extends keyof E = keyof E,
        V1 = Exclude<E[K1], void>,
        K2 extends keyof V1 = keyof V1,
        V2 extends V1[K2]= V1[K2]
        >(collection: C, entityId: string, path: K1 | [K1] | [K1, K2]): C
```

For this example the typings are quite verbose as they're used to type-check the passed in

The above typings work, only problem is that a path to a non-number type is still valid.

```
I tried something like the below to force it to only allow numbers

export function increment<
    C extends Collection<any>,
    E = C extends Collection<infer U> ? U : never,
    K1 extends keyof E = keyof E,
    V1 extends E[K1]= E[K1]
    >(collection: C, entityId: string, path: K1 | [K1]): C
export function increment<
    C extends Collection<any>,
    E = C extends Collection<infer U> ? U : never,
    K1 extends keyof E = keyof E,
    V1 = Extract<Exclude<E[K1], void>, number>, // Note the Extract
    K2 extends keyof V1 = keyof V1,
    V2 extends V1[K2]= V1[K2]
    >(collection: C, entityId: string, path: K1 | [K1] | [K1, K2]): C
```

But the above does not enforce the constraint as expected

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter available keys by the type of property. Taking a cue from the [`Omit`](http://ideasintosoftware.com/typescript-advanced-tricks/) type we can use conditional types to create a type that will filter out properties based on property type.

```
type FilterKeysByType<T, U> = ({[P in keyof T]: T[P] extends U ? P: never } & { [x: string]: never })[keyof T];  
// If there is a single key, it must be a key of a number field
export function increment<
    C extends Collection<any>,
    E = C extends Collection<infer U> ? U : never,
    K1 extends FilterKeysByType<E, number | undefined> = FilterKeysByType<E, number | undefined>,
    V1 extends Exclude<E[K1], void> = Exclude<E[K1], void>
>(collection: C, entityId: string, path: K1 | [K1]): C
// If there are two keys, the first key, can be any  type, but the second key must be the key of a number field 
export function increment<
    C extends Collection<any>,
    E = C extends Collection<infer U> ? U : never,
    K1 extends keyof E = keyof E,
    V1 = Exclude<E[K1], void>,
    K2 extends FilterKeysByType<V1, number| undefined> = FilterKeysByType<V1, number| undefined>,
    V2 extends V1[K2]= V1[K2]
    >(collection: C, entityId: string, path: [K1, K2]): C

// Usage
declare var c : Collection<Comment>;

interface Comment extends Entity{
    name: string;
    value: number;
    optValue?: number;
    subcomment: Comment;
    optSubcomment?: Comment;
}

increment(c, "", "value"); //ok
increment(c, "", "optValue"); //ok
increment(c, "", "name");// error
increment(c, "", ["subcomment", "value"]); // ok
increment(c, "", ["subcomment", "optValue"]); // ok
increment(c, "", ["subcomment", "name"]); // error
increment(c, "", ["optSubcomment", "value"]); // ok
increment(c, "", ["optSubcomment", "optValue"]); // ok
increment(c, "", ["optSubcomment", "name"]); // error
```

Comment: 10x for the interesting and knowledgable answers. This works great, thanks!

Comment: @Tarlen Updated the answer to support optional `number` properties  (`number|undefined`)

Answer (score 2):

I try not to break out conditional types unless I can't solve the problem without them (since they sometimes have spooky inference properties I can't wrap my brain around).  So how about these typings instead?

```
declare function increment<
 C extends Collection<Entity & Record<K1,Record<K2,number>>>, 
 K1 extends string, 
 K2 extends string>(collection: C, entityId: string, path: [K1, K2]): C;
declare function increment<
 C extends Collection<Entity & Record<K1, number>>, 
 K1 extends string>(collection: C, entityId: string, path: K1 | [K1]): C;
```

There is only `C` and `K1` (and maybe `K2`).  The idea is that `C` should be a `Collection<Entity & Something>`, where `Something` is either a `Record<K1, number>` or a `Record<K1, Record<K2, number>>`, depending on how many elements are in `path`.  (In case it matters, `Record<K extends string, V>` is defined as `{[P in K]: V}` and it just means "an object with keys of type `K` and values of type `V`".)

You can verify that it behaves as desired:

```
interface Ent extends Entity {
  stats: {
    total: number,
    color: string
  }
  height: number,
  name: string
}

declare const myCollection: Collection<Ent>;

increment(myCollection, 'some-id', ['stats', 'total']); // okay
increment(myCollection, 'some-id', 'height'); // okay
increment(myCollection, 'some-id', ['height']); // okay

increment(myCollection, 'some-id', ['stats']); // error
increment(myCollection, 'some-id', ['stats', 'name']); // error
increment(myCollection, 'some-id', ['name']); // error
increment(myCollection, 'some-id', ['stats', 'color']); // error
increment(myCollection, 'some-id', ['random']); // error
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Although not part of the description above, the problem with this is that it will fail for when the path contains optional attributes. The types should still work for optional attributes, as the implementation will return early if a path is not reachable

Comment: @Tarlen this almost works if you replace record with a partial record `type PartialRecord<K extends string, T> = { [P in K]?: T; };`. This would restrict to only number properties, but would allow random properties. Very interesting approach though :)

Comment: Could you elaborate on your sentence "This would restrict to only number properties, but would allow random properties"? :)

Comment: @Tarlen. With the `PartialRecord` all the test cases jcalz has in his answer pass, except for the last one, where he has a random property name. I'm hoping he has a solution for it, I like his approach better. Conditional  types are cool but he is right, they get weird, I tend to go to them too quickly :)

Comment: Ah, got it. Yes I agree that conditional types takes a bit of getting used to. Jcalz approach is a better easier to comprehend, especially for someone new to TS (myself included) :)

Comment: Yeah, that's an interesting wrinkle, since the structural type system is willing to accept that a `Collection<Ent>` is also a `Collection<Ent & {random?: number}>`.   I'm guessing you might need conditional types to de-optionalize the optional types before checking the keys.  Not sure if @TitianCernicova-Dragomir's solution works for optionals either.

Comment: @jcalz I thought it did, but then i tested, but there was a small wrinkle if the number property was optional, but I updated and it works :)